# Trying to sum all but it is giving me the error builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for x in range (1,101):
    Mitchell_Trubisky_rec = ("Mitchell Trubisky for ", x, " yards")
    Mitchell_Trubisky_Recyds = sum(line_holder.count(Mitchell_Trubisky_rec))
    print (Mitchell_Trubisky_Recyds)
```

Trying to sum all but it is giving me the error builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question title mentions " Mitchell_Trubisky_Rec20yds", but that variable / function name is not contained in the code snippet you posted. Re-check your code for spelling errors in the variable names, and if you're still stuck, please post a [MCVE]

Comment: What type is the variable `line_holder`? If you are calling a `count` method from it, it is probably returning an integer. Then you are trying to `sum` the integer, which is triggering the error.  To see it, try to do `sum(1)` and you'll get the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.